# How do I post XML to an API using ASP.NET Core 5?

Tags: c#, xml, api, asp.net-core

I'm creating an application which talks to an external API, the external API only accepts XML posts for dealing with information.  I've written most of it and I'm at a point where I need to feed the XML information which includes the DTD to the API and I cannot get it to work.

***CarApiService***

This is where I'm struggling, I have the required XML which I need to post and so I thought I would used the `XmlDocument` to load it, then, rather than using `PostAsync` I could use `PostAsXmlAsync` which is more appropriate.

```
public async Task<string> RequestParts(string partNumber = "0")
{
    //Store any errors as a string
    string errors;            

    //LoadXML
    XmlDocument document = new();
    document.LoadXml("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!DOCTYPE gmPartsRequest PUBLIC '-//GeneralMotors//DTD GmPartsRequest v1//EN' 'http://dtd.generalmotors.com/parts_request_version1.dtd'>" +
            "<partsService version='1.4' dealershipId='xxx'></partsService>");

    //Create HttpClient
    var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("external");

    try
    {
        var postData = await client.PostAsXmlAsync(client.BaseAddress, document);

        errors = null;

        return something.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errorString = $"There was an error getting your parts data: { ex.Message }";
        return errors;
    }            
}
```

There are a few things that bother me about my above code and I'm hoping someone can help:

- PostAsXmlAsync returns an error when it executes and I'm not sure how to resolve it:

> There was an error getting your parts data: Type
> 'System.Xml.XmlElement' with data contract name
> 'XmlElement:[http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Xml'](http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Xml%27) is not
> expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known
> types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by
> adding them to the list of known types passed to
> DataContractSerializer.

- Given that I store the API information in the startup file, is there any way to avoid having to supply the PostAsXmlAsync with the base address in this way?
- Should this really be returning as a string given that I'm supposed to be posting and receiving XML?

Comment: Follow the instructions that comes with the API.  I cannot tell from the code posted what IP is being used.  It looks like from the error message your connection is completing since you got a respon se. Don't worry about the type of response (string) until you resolve the error message.  the PostAsXmlAsync isn't giving an compiler error which indicates the method expects an XmlDocument.  The error message indicates the contract name in the xml data is not declared as a namespace.  So I think the string inside the document.LoadXml() method need to be modified to add more namespaces.

Comment: [`PostAsXmlAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh944689(v=vs.118)) takes a value and serialises it as XML. It is not intended that that value *is* XML.